# Which algorithm is better (and why) in terms of complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Suppose there are two algorithm, the first algorithm has a time complexity of O(n^2), the second algorithm has a time complexity of O(n(log n)^d-2), where n is the number of points in the data set and d is the number of dimensions. Which one is better in terms of time complexity. Can anyone please explain the difference in detail.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave It's a precise question about an aspect of programming with a clear answer that nobody can really argue about once shown correct. I'd say on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O complexity is only useful for comparing very large numbers. In other words, you can compare two big-O expressions when the number you are interested in becomes huge.

The simplest way to do this is to divide the two expressions and find out the limit.

- If the limit is 0, the denominator is more dominant and therefore slower.
- If the limit is infinite, the numerator is more dominant and therefore slower.
- If the limit is anything in between, the two are comparable to each. Big-O alone can't can't tell you which is faster for large numbers.

I'll use SageMath. I'll assume `n` is the thing that grows and `d` is constant.

```
lim n->inf (n(log n)^d-2)/(n^2) = 0
```

Seems like `O(n^2)` is slower. Now let's say `d` also grows, comparably to `n`. So let's put `d = a*n` into the equation:

```
lim n->inf (n(log n)^(an)-2)/(n^2) = +inf
```

Now `O(n(log n)^d-2)` is slower. How about when `d` grows, but comparably to `log n`?

```
lim n->inf (n(log n)^(a log n)-2)/(n^2) = +inf
```

Again, `O(n(log n)^d-2)` would be slower.

#### So what does this tell us?

It tells us that as long as the number of dimensions is bounded and `n` isn't, the `O(n^2)` algorithm would be slower. However, as with all big-O results, this only applies to infinite `n`. For any bounded `n`, you will have to test to see which performs better.

#### Notes

Sagemath setup used:

```
var ("a, b, n")
assume (n, 'integer')
assume (b, 'integer')
assume (n > 0)
assume (b > 0)
assume (a > 0)
```

Queries:

```
limit((n(log(n))^b-2)/(n^2), n=oo)
limit((n(log(n))^(a*n)-2)/(n^2), n=oo)
limit((n(log(n))^(a*log(n))-2)/(n^2), n=oo)
```